# pandas return subset based on columnA.isin.list(columnB)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
             userid  number  weight mask
0    17cf2504d0c7       1      1    56
1    17cf2504d0c7       2      5    56
2    17cf2504d0c7       3      3    123
```

I'm simply trying to return a subset where the "weight" appears in the list of numbers "mask"

```
             userid  number  weight mask
1    17cf2504d0c7       2      5    56
2    17cf2504d0c7       3      3    123
```

I appear to be stumped short of using an iterator, which seems a waste of pandas.

Comment: How are "5" and "3" in mask?

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight... you want to return the rows with index `1` and `2` because number `5` (weights) appears in the mask `56` and `3` appears in `123`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, RafaelC, exactly. It seems to me such a simple problem, but thus far nothing I've tried the last two hours has worked. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way would be to convert your integers to `set` and use set subtraction.

```
mask_ = df.weight.astype(str).apply(set).sub(df['mask'].astype(str).apply(set)).str.len().eq(0)
```

Then

```
df.loc[mask_, :]


    userid          number  weight  mask
1   17cf2504d0c7    2       5       56
2   17cf2504d0c7    3       3       123
```